# Can I export to Google Sheets from Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

How can I export data (e.g. a pandas Dataframe) to a google sheet?

1. Is there a high level library to do this or do I have to use the Google sheets API?
2. If Datalab is running on a GCE VM using a service account how can I authorize it to access Google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a high level library to do this or do I have to use the Google sheets API?**

One potential option is to use the `gspread` library.

**If Datalab is running on a GCE VM using a service account how can I authorize it to access Google sheets?**
Here is a working example of how to authenticate a service account using `oauth2client` version 2.2.0.

```
!pip install gspread
import oauth2client
import gspread

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('PathToTheServiceAccountJsonFile.json', scopes =  ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds'])
gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
gs.open('TitleOfGoogleSheetsFileGoesHere').sheet1
```

Make sure to share the Google Sheet with the email address of your service account. For example xxxx@.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

Please let me know if you have any trouble so I can update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that shows how to export a Pandas DataFrame into a Google Sheet.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B7I8C_4vGdF6SDdBT1pJZlZTU1k

The example shows:

1. Authenticating to Google Sheets using your account.
2. Using the [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) API to create a new sheet.
3. Creating a random Pandas DataFrame to be exported. And,
4. Exporting the values from the DataFrame into the Google Sheet.